# How to alter external schema IAM Role in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Based on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA.html

I have my schema declared in the following way:

```
create external schema spectrum_schema
from data catalog
database 'spectrum_db'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRedshiftRole,arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myS3Role'
catalog_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myAthenaRole'
create external database if not exists;
```

I decided I want to change my IAM Role for this schema and having something like `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/moreBeautifulRole` instead.

Is it possible to change it? Ideally I'd like to change it with something like

```
ALTER SCHEMA spectrum_schema IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/moreBeautifulRole'
```

without destroying the schema. Please share the available options.

Answer (score 2):

After confirming with AWS Support, at the date posting this answer it is **not supported** to edit the IAM Role in an existing External Schema.

Available options I can think are:

1. Create a new External Schema with the `moreBeautifulRole`
2. Add Policy to `myS3Role` with the required permission - or edit the already assigned one
3. Drop and recreate external schema and depending objects (including external tables). Using [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/) is not too bad as approach